# Rational points on varieties whose anticanonical bundle is nef but not ample

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points, heights

Is the following plausible?

"If $X$ is a variety over $\mathbf{Q}$ whose anticanonical bundle $L$ is nef but not ample, there is a number field $K$ such that $X(K)$ contains an infinite set of points whose height with respect to $L$ is bounded above."

This would be sort of partial converse to "ample heights are Northcott," I suppose.

If $L$ is $0$, then this sort of thing is supposed to be true, because a variety $X$ with trivial canonical is generally supposed to have a Zariski-dense set of rational points (which would all, of course, have anticanonical height $0$) over some number field. (This is known for abelian varieties, only suspected but I think pretty strongly believed for K3 surfaces.)  The same argument applies to something like $E \times \mathbf{P}^1$ with $E$ and elliptic curve; points on $E$ provide the desired infinite set.

But basically I don't really have enough of a mental fund of examples of varieties with anticanonical nef but not ample to have a good sense of whether this is reasonable.  (Note:  Cao has a theorem that projective + nef anticanonical implies fibered in rationally connected varieties over something with trivial canonical bundle, but I don't immediately see how this helps.)

Comment: If $L$ is semiample, so a power of $L$ defines a map $X \to \mathbb P^n$, then the points of $X(K)$ of bounded $L$-height have finitely many images to $\mathbb P^n$, so it is equivalent to ask the fibers of this map have infinitely many $K$-rational points. Assuming various big conjectures, it's equivalent to ask that the positive-dimensional fibers of this map are not all hyperbolic. So this gives a purely geometric statement to look for.